# Using gathered accelerometer data for Tizen Acitivty Recognition API

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

At the moment, I'm working on some research for my university regarding activity recognition API's. I've created a dataset containing data from the accelerometer and I'm testing it on various Activity Recognition API's.

One API that caught my eye was the Activity Recognition API from Tizen. I've looked into the documentation of this API and I had some difficulties in understanding how it worked, and more importantly, if/how it is possible to use your 'own' Accelerometer in order to detect activities.

Therefore, my question is as follows: "Is it possible to use accelerometer data from an outside source with the Tizen Activity Recognition API and if so, how is this possible?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your query in short, there is no provision to handle external data and detect the activity.
There is the `activity_start_recognition()` API, which takes what activity we want to detect like `ACTIVITY_STATIONARY`, `ACTIVITY_WALK`, `ACTIVITY_RUN` and `ACTIVITY_IN_VEHICLE` as input parameter along with callback function. On detecting the activity Activity Recognition module calls the callback function.
So in the existing API there is no provision to feed input data like accelerometer data (or any other kind of data) and detect the activity.

Comment: Okay, that is unfortunate. However, would it be possible to 'fake' readings from the accelerometer sensor? What I mean is that I can call a method in which I put the gathered data from the Accelerometer, which can result into detecting an activity?